# Changing location in `plate` object in `bayesnet`

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to space out the writing `$1 \le i \le m$` and `$1 \le i' \le m'$` in the following figure created using the `bayesnet` library, but it seems to always put things in the bottom right corner, I'm now sure how to get overlapping plates formatted nicely, ideally `$1 \le i \le m$` is on the bottom left of its respective plate. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \tikz{ %
        \node[obs] (y_idash) {$\by_{i i'}$} ; % 
        \node[latent, left=of y_idash] (u_i) {$\bu_i$} ; %
        \node[latent, right=of y_idash] (ud_i) {$\bu'_i$} ; %
        \plate[inner sep=0.35cm, xshift=-0.2cm, yshift=0.12cm] {plate1} {(u_i) (y_idash)} {$1 \le i \le m$}; %
        \plate[inner sep=0.35cm, xshift=-0.2cm, yshift=0.12cm] {plate2} {(ud_i) (y_idash)} {$1 \le i' \le m'$};
      \edge {u_i,ud_i} {y_idash} ; %
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
%note - compi[![enter image description here][1]][1]led with pdflatex
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed. This library uses deprecated syntax and a lot of hard coding. On the long run I recommend to abandon it. For now,

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \tikz{ %
        \node[obs] (y_idash) {$\boldsymbol{y}_{i i'}$} ; % 
        \node[latent, left=of y_idash] (u_i) {$\boldsymbol{u}_i$} ; %
        \node[latent, right=of y_idash] (ud_i) {$\boldsymbol{u}'_i$} ; %
        \tikzset{plate caption/.style={caption, node distance=0, inner sep=0pt,
        below left=5pt and 0pt of #1.south,text height=1.2em,text depth=0.3em}}
        \plate[inner sep=0.35cm, xshift=0cm, yshift=0.12cm] {plate1} {(u_i) (y_idash)} {$1 \le i \le m$}; %
        \tikzset{plate caption/.style={caption, node distance=0, inner sep=0pt,
        below right=5pt and 0pt of #1.south,text height=1.2em,text depth=0.3em}}
        \plate[inner sep=0.35cm, xshift=0cm, yshift=0.12cm] {plate2} {(ud_i) (y_idash)} {$1 \le i' \le m'$};
      \edge {u_i,ud_i} {y_idash} ; %
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please let me know if you want to have solution without this library.

Here is an attempt to redo some of the elements, which I shamelessly stole from the bayesnet library, with the more modern syntax. The way this works is that there is a style `Bayes net` that locally installs the styles in a `tikzpicture`. So this will coexist with other libraries. And I redid one command, `\edges`, in an arguably more Ti*k*Zy way, namely via `insert path`. Result:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,fit,arrows.meta,chains}
\tikzset{Bayes net/.code=\BayesTemp}
\edef\BayesTemp{\noexpand\tikzset{latent/.style={circle,fill=white,draw=black,inner sep=1pt,
minimum size=20pt,font=\noexpand\fontsize{10}{10}\noexpand\selectfont},
obs/.style={latent,fill=gray!25},
const/.style={rectangle, inner sep=0pt},
factor/.style={rectangle, fill=black,minimum size=5pt, inner sep=0pt},
det/.style={latent, diamond},
plate/.style={draw, rectangle, rounded corners, fit=##1},
wrap/.style={inner sep=0pt, fit=##1},
gate/.style={draw, rectangle, dashed, fit=##1},
caption/.style={font=\noexpand\footnotesize, node distance=0},
plate caption/.style={caption, node distance=0, inner sep=0pt,
below left=5pt and 0pt of ##1.south east},
every label/.append style={caption},
>={Triangle[]},
edges/.style args={from ##1 to ##2}{insert path={
foreach \noexpand\XX in {##1} { %
     foreach \noexpand\YY in {##2} { %
        (\noexpand\XX) edge (\noexpand\YY) }}
}}}} 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[Bayes net]
        \node[obs] (y_idash) {$\boldsymbol{y}_{i i'}$} ; 
        \node[latent, left=of y_idash,label={[name=ulab,text height=1.2em]below:$1 \le i \le m$}] (u_i) {$\boldsymbol{u}_i$} ; %
        \node[latent, right=of y_idash,label={[name=ulab',text height=1.2em]below:$1 \le i' \le m'$}] (ud_i) {$\boldsymbol{u}'_i$} ; %
        \draw[->,edges=from {u_i,ud_i} to {y_idash}];
        \node[plate=(u_i) (y_idash) (ulab)]{};
        \node[plate=(ud_i) (y_idash) (ulab')]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this is not at all a complaint about the bayesnet library. I am sure that at the time it was written this was great progress.

Comment: thank you! regarding your comments on the library, would you recommend something else?

Comment: @dimebucker91 This library is just a collection of styles and very simple commands, which use the `fit` library and other libraries. Its syntax is deprecated. And, as you noted yourself, it is not very flexible either. I personally would just use a minimal set of styles and then plain Ti*k*Z with these libraries. And if you have a question on how to implement a given feature, you will find answers here and on similar sites, or can ask a new question.